# How to force Xfce4-Terminal to xterm

Tags: colors, terminal-emulator, xfce4-terminal

I know it's usually the other way around: most questions are about people wanting to have **more** colors in their terminals. But I have been quite happy with the 16-colors scheme that I set years ago and I wasn't very pleased when I noticed Vim was using its own set of colours instead of the ones I hand-picked.

So what I want is that my Vim looks like this:

[image]

not like this:

[image]

(Please ignore difference in font sizes and background; I'm only interested in the foreground colors, so I'm showing screenshots taken from different computers: one prior to the upgrade that changed my settings and another with the new color settings.)

I figured I would do this by adding

```
TERM=xterm
```

to my `~/.bashrc`. But when I do this, Vim defaults to `set bg=dark`, even though that particular line is commeted out in `/etc/vim/vimrc` (second screenshot).

I can get a color scheme that's very close to what I'm used to by issuing `colorscheme peachpuff` in `~/.vimrc`, but then it breaks `hlsearch`...

Comment: I believe in the xfce4-terminal preferences you can set each of the 16 colours. This is what appears wrong when I'm looking at the screenshots but I might be wrong.

Comment: What is the emulation setting in Edit->Preferences->Compatibilty of xfce4-terminal? That should be set to `xterm`.

Comment: @Munir I was looking for that option, but it was removed at some point between version 0.6 (the one in Debian stable) and 0.8 (the one currently in testing).

Comment: Ah...okay. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: XFCE Terminal exports `COLORTERM=Terminal`, which (supposing you're using something like Fedora) industrious packagers may have scripted into something to defeat your attempt to customize the terminal.